# How can I see an iPhone Smart Battery Case serial number using macOS console?

Tags: iphone, battery, accessories

My iPhone XS Max Smart Battery Case's serial number is extremely difficult to make out due to the color and wear on the fabric.

How do I use macOS Console.app to connect to my iPhone to see what the Smart Battery Case serial number is?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your iPhone into the Smart Battery Case.
2. Unlock your iPhone.
3. Open Console.app on macOS.
4. Plug your Lightning cable into your computer.
5. Plug in the other end of the Lightning cable into your iPhone via the Smart Battery Case Lightning port.
6. Your unlocked iPhone may ask if you trust this computer. Select Trust and enter your iPhone passcode.
7. In Console.app, select your iPhone on the sidebar.
8. Type `Accessory Identifier` into the Console.app search bar.
9. In the Console.app window, you will see a number of items under process `sharingd` with text in the message containing `In powersource description`.
10. Select one of these items and look for the line `"Battery Case", "Accessory Identifier" :`. The serial number for the Smart Battery Case will be listed there.

[image: An image of the Console.app containing an entry including a serial number for the Smart Battery Case.]

Answer (score 1):

This is not using the Console.app, but if you just want the serial number, the easiest thing to do is navigate to `Settings > Privacy > Analytics > Start Diagnostics`.

Comment: Could you include a screenshot? Does "Start Diagnostics" show while the Smart Battery Case is disconnected?

Comment: Sorry I discovered that was something that Apple Support enabled while I was on the phone with them. Not sure why they don’t have a similar feature normally.